# How do I expect the exact part of the crash? in iOS Crash Log EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)

Tags: ios, swift, sigabrt

I was rejected to review the app, but there is no problem when I tested it with a practical device.
So I don't know where the problem occurs.

```
Crash Log:
Last Exception Backtrace:
0 CoreFoundation 0x1c6349e48 \__exceptionPreprocess + 164
1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x1bf6938d8 objc_exception_throw + 60
2 UIKitCore 0x1c8924838 -\[UIStoryboard initWithBundle:storyboardFileName:identifierToN
3 UIKitCore 0x1c8924394 -\[UISceneConfiguration initWithName:sessionRole:\] + 1572
4 UIKitCore 0x1c898167c +\[UISceneConfiguration configurationWithName:sessionRole:\] + 64
5 UIKitCore 0x1c898f5c8 -\[UISceneSession \_initWithPersistentIdentifier:sessionRole:configurationName:\] + 168
6 UIKitCore 0x1c8723230 -\[UIApplication \_connectUISceneFromFBSScene:transitionContext:\] + 408
7 UIKitCore 0x1c8722ee8 -\[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:\] + 372
8 UIKitCore 0x1c8722d08 -\[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:\] + 288
9 FrontBoardServices 0x1dc064e90 -\[FBSScene \_callOutQueue_agent_didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:\] + 344
10 FrontBoardServices 0x1dc0a48f8 \__92-\[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createSceneWithIdentity:parameters:transitionContext:completion:\]\_block_invoke.78 + 120
11 FrontBoardServices 0x1dc068c24 -\[FBSWorkspace \_calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:\] + 168
12 FrontBoardServices 0x1dc0a4530 \__92-\[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createSceneWithIdentity:parameters:transitionContext:completion:\]\_block_invoke + 360
13 libdispatch.dylib 0x1cd958fdc \_dispatch_client_callout + 20
14 libdispatch.dylib 0x1cd95ca5c \_dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 264
15 FrontBoardServices 0x1dc072d40 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 52
16 FrontBoardServices 0x1dc0728dc -\[FBSSerialQueue targetQueue_performNextIfPossible\] + 220
17 FrontBoardServices 0x1dc075184 -\[FBSSerialQueue performNextFromRunLoopSource\] + 28
18 CoreFoundation 0x1c6415f34 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28
19 CoreFoundation 0x1c642230c \__CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 176
20 CoreFoundation 0x1c63a6230 \__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 340
21 CoreFoundation 0x1c63bbb8c \__CFRunLoopRun + 836
22 oreFoundation 0x1c63c0ec0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
23  GraphicsServices 0x1ffb6b368 GSEventRunModal + 164  
24  UIKitCore 0x1c88b686c -\[UIApplication run\] + 888
25  UIKitCore 0x1c88b64d0 UIApplicationMain + 340
26  libswiftUIKit.dylib 0x1ceeda308 UIApplicationMain(_::::) + 104
27  MyApp 0x102b7ee8c static UIApplicationDelegate.main() + 104
28  MyApp 0x102b82880 main + 28
30  dyld 0x1e4bd2960 start + 2528
```

I looked for a place where Nil could float in init, but there was no place.
Thank you for your reading

Comment: Did you run a test flight build?  Did you run it on an iPad?  Something went wrong with fetching the initial storyboard scene.

Comment: Since I don't have an iPad, I tested the iPad only with the xcode simulator... :(

Comment: Is your app universal or iPhone only? If it is universal then you really need to test on a real iPad.  The simulator is not a valid test.  Apple reviewers often use an iPad for reviewing iPhone apps.

Comment: It's with the iPad, but there's no code modification, but suddenly there's a crash... Can't you predict by looking at that without a real iPad?.....TT...

Comment: There are differences between debug and release builds, device and simulator builds.  If you have an M1 Mac you could try running your TestFlight build on your Mac.

Comment: Did they send you a crashlog you can symbolicate?

Comment: I tested it with the ipa I uploaded, but there is no problem...Thank you.... :(((((

Comment: I don't know how to symbolate. 

-arch arm64 -o MyApp.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/MyApp -l 0x102b82880   and   
arch arm64 -o MyApp.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/MyApp -l 0x102b82880 main+28    and   
arch arm64 -o MyApp.app.dSYM/MyApp -l main+28 0x102b82880
... ... etc...
I tried everything. I googled everything, but it doesn't come out properly. Please tell me how to do it. plz....